# I screwed up massively when I accidentally moved a file over /usr/bin/python3. Apt and DPKG do not help with any flags

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

Log:

```
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.8-dev' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.8-minimal' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'python3.8' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed

(Reading database ... 274323 files and directories currently installed.)

Removing language-selector-gnome (0.204.2) ...
#this part seems important
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.prerm: 6: py3clean: not found  
dpkg: error processing package language-selector-gnome (--remove):
 installed language-selector-gnome package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127

dpkg: too many errors, stopping
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-selector-gnome.postinst: 6: py3compile: not found

dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed language-selector-gnome package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 language-selector-gnome
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Is overwriting `/usr/bin/python3` mistakenly (not accidentally) all you did to your system?

Comment: I think so, but I also tried to manually purge all files related to python3-overcompensation I guess

Comment: Also I should've known it was a file and not a directory.

Comment: Why does apt require python3?

Also if I deleted that comment sorry

Comment: There are some "suggested" packages (like `python3-debconf`) that are installed along with the `apt` package. These require python3, so I ~suspect~ removing python 3 could have a negative impact on your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to recreate the missing sim-link.
Since the file exists, use the `-f` force flag.

```
sudo ln -s -f /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
```

Comment: The symbolic link failed. ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/bin/python3': File exists. 

The problem isn't that the file is missing, it's that I wrote over it.

Comment: See my change above, use `-f` to overwrite the file that exists.